# Catching data attributes in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, css-selectors, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a data attribute div which Testcafe doesn't seem to find

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Isikukood" data-v-0a9dbb1c="" data-t-id="Login_isikukood">
```

I tried this

```
input[data-t-id="Login_Isikukood"]
```

but without results. Any ideas?

Comment: Just offhand you've used an uppercase `I` in `Ishikukood` when your element uses a lowercase `i`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, this worked `[data-t-id="Login_isikukood"]`